# A complex MapRoute in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, global-asax

I am trying to learn ASP.NET MVC and I have a question that I cannot find a solution. I found some writings about it but couldn't understand it perfectly.

I have many `MapRoute` in my `Global.asax` file and they all look like bellow:

```
routes.MapRoute(
       "Companies", // name it!
       "Bathroom/Companies/{Filtre}", // Route name
       new { controller = "Bathroom", action = "Companies", Filtre = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

and this MapRoute handles a url like `~/Bathroom/Companies/FilterTest`. but I need have a MapRoute that will handle a URL like `~/Bathroom/Companies/Location/Washington`

How I write the `MapRoute`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want URLs starting exactly with `/Bathroom/Companies/Location/` then use this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Companies",
   "Bathroom/Companies/Location/{Filtre}",
   new { controller = "Bathroom", action = "Companies", Filtre = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This will match `/Bathroom/Companies/Location/Washington` and `/Bathroom/Companies/Location/NewYork`, etc. and you will get `Filtre` parameter in your `Companies` action in `Bathroom` controller.

Comment: lets say the url is /Bathroom/Companies/Location/Washington and what am I supposed to get in the filter?

Comment: In this case the `Filtre` will be `Washington`

Comment: so there is no difference if there is "Location" or not. I dont get it perfectly. I would like to have a different function that returns ActionResult for "/Bathroom/Companies/Location/Washington"

Comment: Then change `controller = "Bathroom", action = "Companies",` to the controller class and method name you want.